# JavaScript - Distinct values in array from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a `data` like this:

```
data: [
    {id: 1, name: 'device1', status: ['online','idle']},
    {id: 2, name: 'device2', status: ['network-error']},
    {id: 3, name: 'device3', status: ['online','idle']},
    {id: 4, name: 'device4', status: ['offline','inoperative']},
    
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to get distinct values of `status` in an array like this:

```
['online', 'idle', 'network-error', 'offline', 'inoperative']
```

I used this code:

```js
let status = [...new Set(data.map(({deviceTags}) => deviceTags))];
```

But it returns:

```
[["online", "idle"], ["network-error"], ["online", "idle"], ["offline", "inoperative"]]
```

How can achieve distinct values of them?

Comment: result = [...new Set([your return array here].flat())]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `.map()`

> The `flatMap()` method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level. It is identical to a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) followed by a [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'device1', deviceTags: ['online','idle']},
    {id: 2, name: 'device2', deviceTags: ['network-error']},
    {id: 3, name: 'device3', deviceTags: ['online','idle']},
    {id: 4, name: 'device4', deviceTags: ['offline','inoperative']}
]

const status = [...new Set(data.flatMap(({deviceTags}) => deviceTags))];

console.log(status);
```